# Are the Google Map/Places APIs compatible with iOS 6?

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit, apple-maps

Are the Google Map/Places APIs compatible with iOS 6? I'm playing with iOS 6 API but I'm very confused about how is Apple Maps going to support Google Maps.

Comment: I believe iOS6 is using Apple Maps, not Google Maps. That being said, I do not believe there is any cross-compatibility between then, as Apple is transtioning to relying on the own exclusive services. It seems as though Apple is annoyed with using software from other companies in their own products. Maybe someday they will have AppleTube and Apple Search in their iOS too... lol

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using just Apple Framework so the MapKit it will automatically use Apple Maps in iOS 6 but will remain the same functionality!

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the demo from Apple at WWDC, you will see that Apple comes with its own map tiles and aggregates content from Yelp.

Google is out. No support in the maps app. No support in the MapKit.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Google's TOS state that you can only use their data on their maps. If you use their Javascript API and then place that data on Apple maps in iOS6 you'd be breaking those terms.

Answer (score 0):

I think so :)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html

Maps
In iOS 6 and later, Map Kit is built on a new infrastructure hosted by Apple. Earlier iOS releases will continue to use Google’s service.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, I found that ...

the apps using Google Maps JavaScript API v3 (html5 built apps, e.g. phonegap-based), survived from this major change!